# how to present a popupview from a UIBarButtonItem inside a UITextView accessoryView

Tags: swift, uitextview, uibarbuttonitem, accessoryview, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I'm having difficulties presenting a popup-view with a sourceView that is a UIBarbuttonItem of a UITextView's accessoryview. It seems as if views inside a Keyboard are somehow not treated the same as other views in the view-hierarchy. When I end keyboard editing, the popup-view appears on the underlaying viewcontroller's view. Here's some code:

```
   @objc func foregroundColorPressed(button : UIBarButtonItem)
   {
      let colorSelectionPopup = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ColorSelectionPopup")
      colorSelectionPopup.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
      let popOver = colorSelectionPopup.popoverPresentationController!
      colorSelectionPopup.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
      popOver.delegate = self
      popOver.permittedArrowDirections = .up
      popOver.barButtonItem = button
      //popOver.sourceView = button.theView
      //popOver.sourceRect = (button.theView?.bounds)!

       getCurrentViewController()?.present(colorSelectionPopup, animated: true, completion: {
        //
    })
```

and my popoverPresentationDelegate method is

```
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
       return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seemed that the problem was the arrow direction property of the popoverPresentationController. Setting that to .none or .down made the code work.